# php mass email sending issue

Tags: php, email, pear

I want to send welcome notification or other type of daily EMAILS for my user's, those are more than 50k before i was using simple mail function. so getting stuck after few emails then after trying to google I got to know something about pear mail then I try that too but not able to send email for all. user getting this error

```
 require_once "Mail.php";
 require_once "Mail/mime.php";
 $from = "Justprobe <justprobe@justprobe.com>";
$to = "Pratya <pratyatech@gmail.com>";
$subject = "xxxxxxxx";
$body = "xxxxxxx";
$host = "mail.justprobe.com";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mime = new Mail_mime();
$mime->setHTMLBody($body);

$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
$mail = $smtp->send($email_id, $headers, $body);
```

ERROR:

```
    Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 550, response: justprobe@justprobe.com exceeded rate limit ( 100.1 / 1h ))]


    Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 550, response: justprobe@justprobe.com exceeded rate limit ( 100.1 / 1h ))]


    Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 550, response: justprobe@justprobe.com exceeded rate limit ( 100.1 / 1h ))]


    Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 550, response: justprobe@justprobe.com exceeded rate limit ( 100.1 / 1h ))]


    Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 550, response: justprobe@justprobe.com exceeded rate limit ( 100.1 / 1h ))]
```

Comment: In this way you would end up blacklisting you server ip. I would suggest have a 3rd party tieup to send emails. It would also be a faster way to send it.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply could you suggest any third party service provider

Comment: I have added some options in my answer. Please check.

Comment: Let me know if the answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the below options:

https://mandrillapp.com/

http://mailchimp.com/

https://www.klaviyo.com/

You also get great apis to integrate inorder to send emails.

Also check NetCore in case you are looking for Indian service provider.

Comment: Mandrillapp.com plays very nice with `composer` and `php`, you can even ignore `smtp` when using their `api`.